# mongodb design issue. Should I use sharding cluster or divide documents to different collection when I have multiple same value of key

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a Collection looks like :

```
[{
  "company": "A",
  "name": "N1",
  "age": "C1"
},{
  "company": "A",
  "name": "N2",
  "age": "C2"
},{
  "company": "B",
  "name": "N3",
  "age": "C3"
}]
```

I have 2 optimization strategy：

**1. sharding**

sharding key: company.
Then company A / company B should divide to two shards.
And I will store them in different mongod server.

**2. divide them by collection name**

company A 's collection is

```
col_A = [{
"name": "N1",
  "age": "C1"
},{
  "name": "N2",
  "age": "C2"
}]
```

company B 's collection is

```
col_B = [{
  "name": "N3",
  "age": "C3"
}]
```

Which plan is better?

I think the second solution reduces the number of primary keys and the amount of data. But it will cause the number of collections to increase.

Which should I choose? Thanks a lot...

Comment: You need to tell about what your data is about and how it will be used. Also, the amount of data and the kind of important crud queries you perform on the data in your application. These details are important and generally determine how the data is modeled.

Comment: You say "I have a Collection", i.e. you have **one** collection. Why do you like to split a collection (where all documents seem to have the same structure) into multiple collections? How many different companies does your collection have?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit   Thanks for reply..  I have abount 200 companies, and 1,000,000 data size each company. So I thought maybe split them to 200 collections, the query performance would be better ...

Comment: I don't think so, the application just gets more complicated when you use multiple collections. 200M records is not so much nowadays. I would suggest sharding.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data size and how your scaling strategy.
Sharding is the better approach when you are talking about the future data size as it will better handle horizontal scaling. with your second option, it won't be easy to scale horizontally.

If you're taking the first option, you probably want to consider other potential sharding keys that could have the best performance result for your query. For example, if one company was making the most queries through the entire application, the sharding base on the company might not be the best.

One more advantage of sharding is you don't need to refractory your model/repository that much compared to using multiple collections.